# pandas add columns ,note The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas

I want do add a column to dataframe a,

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]],columns=['A','B'])
if a['B'] > a['A']:
    a['C']='是'
else:
    a['C']='否'
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
#swapped 2,1
a = pd.DataFrame([[2,1],[3,4]],columns=['A','B'])
a['C'] = np.where(a['B']>a['A'], '是','否')
print (a)
   A  B  C
0  2  1  否
1  3  4  是
```

Problem with your code is if use:

```
print (a['B']>a['A'])
0    False
1     True
dtype: bool
```

it return boolean mask and `if` cannot decide what to do.

Check also [using if truth statements with pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, where or [numpy.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html?highlight=numpy%20select#numpy-select):

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[2,1],[3,4]],columns=['A','B'])
a['C'] = np.select([a['B']>a['A']], '是', default = '否')
print(a)
```

Returns:

```
   A  B  C
0  2  1  否
1  3  4  是
```

---

Which easily scales to more conditions:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[2,1],[3,4],[1,10]],columns=['A','B'])

condlist = [
    a['B'] > 5*a['A'],
    a['B'] > a['A']
]
valuelist = ['是', '否']

a['C'] = np.select(condlist, valuelist, default=np.nan)
print(a)
```

Returns:

```
   A   B    C
0  2   1   nan
1  3   4    否
2  1  10    是
```

Answer (score 0):

Also a option is

```
np.choose()
```

Which is implemented in

```
np.choose('是','否')
```